# SQL, Flask: can't access database from html template

Tags: python, flask

I know that sessions are available through html templates like so:

```
<h1>{{session.name}}</h1>
```

That worked for a while but when I wanted to add more attributes to a user like an about text, I couldn't store everything in the session. The email and password I do store in the session because they are actually used. I can retrieve a user with the email and get the name like so:

```
User.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first().name
```

However, when I try putting it into html like this it says that Users is undefined.

```
<li>Name: {{Users.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first().name}}</li>
```

I guess some things like that are not carried over but is there a straightforward way to get all variables from the main.py file I was using there?

I even tried doing

```
return redirect(url_for('user', \
usr=Users.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first().__dict__))
```

in main.py and then doing

```
<li class="list-group-item">Name: {{usr['name']}}</li>
```

but that wouldn't work either for some reason. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution I tried doesn't work because Flask doesn't have a reference to Users. The second doesn't work either because I passed it through url_for and not the actual render template function so it wouldn't know what to do with it.

My final solution would be this:

```
usr = Users.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first().__dict__
    return render_template('user.html', name=usr['name'], status=usr['status'], 
    about=usr['about'])
```

I could also just have passed the entire dict as before I believe.